# How to run a python function in a tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter, web-scraping

I made some functions which grab information from websites like weather or news using Python and BeautifulSoup. Basically web scraping.
Now I would like to run them in a different window with Tkinter. How could I implement the weather function, as an example, in my code in order to have it shown not just in the terminal of my text editor but in this Tkinter window?

That's my code for the Tkinter window:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from weather import weather_def # that's the function I made in a different file

# main
window = Tk()
window.title('My Overview')
window.configure(background='white')

# create a entry text box
textentry = Entry(window, width=15, bg='white')
textentry.place(x=80, y=40)

# create label
label = Label(window, text='Empty label', bg='white', fg='black', font='none 12 bold')
label.place(x=80, y=120)        

# add a submit button, command=click, width=10
btn = Button(window, text='Show information', command=weather_def)
btn.place(x=80, y=80)


# run the main loop
window.mainloop()
```

And that's the function which grabs information about the weather from a website:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url_weather = 'https://www.mein-wetter.com/wetter/ebermannstadt.htm'

# opening up connection, grabbing the page
uClient_weather = uReq(url_weather)
page_html_weather = uClient_weather.read()
uClient_weather.close()

# html parsing
page_soup_weather = soup(page_html_weather, "html.parser")

# grabs containers
containers_weather = page_soup_weather.find('ul', {'class': 'uldet'}).findAll('li')

# grabs time, temperature, text
def weather_def():
    print('Wetter')
    print('::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::')

    for container in containers_weather:
        time = container.findAll('h4')[0].text
        temperature = container.findAll('dd', {'class': 'temp'})[0].text
        image_alt = container.find('img').get('alt')
    
        # only show weather from 6:00 to 23:00
        if int(time) == 00:
            break

        elif int(time[1]) >= 6 or int(time[0]) > 0:
            print(time + ':00 Uhr')
            print(temperature)
            print(image_alt)
            print('-----------------------------------------')
```

Comment: instead of printing  use `insert()` and a Text widget

Comment: I'm pretty new to programming. Could you explain what you mean please?

Comment: create a text widget like so for example: `text = Text(window)` then pack or grid or place it like so for example `text.pack()` (shouldn't really use `place()` since `pack()` and `grid()` are better and can achieve the most) then everywhere You have a `print()` place `text.insert('end', text_that_was_supposed_to_be_printed)`

Answer (score 1):

Hi @jumuell and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have seen the comments, but I am answering your question because I found a problem that the others did not.

For your problem, you need to show multiple lines of text as a result. The `Text` widget allows multiple lines to be typed in it. But the logic part and the GUI part are in separate files.

Create a new Text widget in the GUI file.

```
name_of_text_widget = Text(window)
name_of_text_widget.pack
```

(You can change `pack` to `grid` or `place` as per your wish.)

Then in the function, make a list which has all the data to be returned. In your case it would be:

```
#Add this line at the bottom of the function named `weather_def`
return ['Wetter', ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::', time + ':00 Uhr',
temperature, image_alt, '-----------------------------------------']
```

Create a new function and link it in the GUI file to a button(instead of directly calling `weather_def` function).Then type the following code in there:

```
def function_name():
    #This function should be in the GUI file
    list_from_weather_output = weather_def()
    for i in list_from_weather_output:
        name_of_text_widget.insert(END, i)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Gonna try it out now!

Comment: @jumuell please accept my answer as the best and upvote it if you feel it is.